# Change cursor for QMessageBox and SaveFileDialog

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qmessagebox

In PyQt5 I can change the cursor for an object using:

```
    Object.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
```

For the other buttons I use this class but it does not change the cursors in `QmessageBox` or `Qfiledialog`:

```
class QPushButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QPushButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
```

How can I change the cursor for ALL buttons in `QMessageBox` and `QFileDialog`?

Example of a Messagebox method

```
def onNotConnected(self):
        err = QMessageBox.question(
            self, DONGLE_NOT_CONN, DONGLE_NOT_CONN_MSG, QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)
        if err == QMessageBox.Ok:            
            self.updating_thread(self.device_code)
        else:
            self.restart_program()
```

Comment: QMessageBox has the method setCursor().

Comment: Are you referring to the static methods of QMessageBox ?, you could explain yourself better.

Comment: What about `QFileDialog`?

Comment: QFileDialog also has the setCursor() method.

Comment: I have added further explanation..

Comment: Do you think that inheriting from one class to another with the same name is correct?

Comment: They are changing because your QPushButtons are not the original QPushButtons and you are building them in python, instead the static methods of QMessageBox and QFileDialog are created in C++

Comment: That is what I intended..All buttons now have the correct cursor on.. Can I do the same thing with QMessageBox?

Comment: You could show how you are using the QMessageBox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176869/discussion-between-johnashu-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: I have put an example with QMessageBox in my answer, if you put an example with QFileDialog I could tell you if it can or not, and if it is possible to show you an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QMessageBox` and `QFileDialog` have the `setCursor()` method since they inherit from `QWidget`. But the problem in your case is with static methods since you can not access the object directly.

So the solution is to take advantage of a particular characteristic of these static methods: they are topLevels, so we can filter it using `QApplication.topLevelWidgets()`, but the other problem is that they are blocking so nothing will be executed synchronously, so The trick is to use `QTimer`.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

def onTimeout():
    for w in QtWidgets.QApplication.topLevelWidgets():
        if isinstance(w, QtWidgets.QMessageBox):
            for button in w.buttons():
                button.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent=None)
        self.show()

        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, onTimeout)
        res = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self, 
            "title", 
            "text",  
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Also in your sample that we can filter the filter using the parent of the QMessageBox and possibly the QFileDialog is the window.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent=None)
        self.show()

        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.onTimeout)
        msgBox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self, 
            "title", 
            "text",  
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel)

        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.onTimeout)
        fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 
            "Save File",
            QtCore.QDir.homePath(),
            "Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)",
            "",
            QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)

    def onTimeout(self):
        for w in QtWidgets.QApplication.topLevelWidgets():
            if isinstance(w, QtWidgets.QMessageBox) and w.parent() == self:
                for button in w.buttons():
                    button.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
            elif isinstance(w, QtWidgets.QFileDialog) and w.parent() == self:
                for button in w.findChildren(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
                    button.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```